# Swift - Conceptual, type-check time concerns

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building what I would consider a fairly light application, at least from a web developers point of view. I have messages, posts, what have you, with simple design with images and such. I'm utilizing my old 2012 MacBook Pro to write this application, so I figure that might have something to do with it, but every build takes an obscene amount of time to write, like a minute or two, if at all. I try to add something simple like an image that's clipped to the shape of a circle and apparently that pushes the build past the point where the type-check takes a reasonable amount of time.

It just seems incredible how such a relatively simple application could take so long to write, and even crazier that this type-check is forced upon you, and if it fails you can't even test out your application. Sometimes the type-check error will just get put on a Z-Stack with multiple different views combined after making many changes so it's impossible to tell what made it throw the error so I just have to rework backwards removing things and see what works, it just seems like such an archaic way to write code. I don't know if I'm alone, perhaps if you start in mobile development you get used to it just being the way it is, or as I mentioned it might be due to the lackluster power of my computer in question, but there is no reason an IDE should be super processing intensive, at least from how I see it. I guess I kind of understand Apple's prerogative with forcing this type-checking software on all apps, I guess to prevent apps from having bugs, but honestly it seems half polished sometimes and has never really helped me much with finding errors that I wouldn't have found from just running the build, and has been a detriment to the experience of writing Swift when it just won't build at all because it's having problems type-checking it.

Is this issue with the time it takes to make each build just a reality of XCode and Swift or is it just due to the processing power of the machine I'm writing it on? Both seem equally depressing, in all honesty.

Comment: I assume that you're using SwiftUI, which is still quite rough in some cases. The strict type checking is something that comes with Swift, and it is actually one of its strong points. If you don't like this then Swift is not the language for you. Can you maybe post an example of code that takes a disproportionate long time to compile on your machine?

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI?  It sounds like it. There are improvements in SwiftUI compilation error reporting in Swift 5.2, so make sure you have the latest Xcode, but honestly you are trying to use an 8 year old computer with an IDE that is continually parsing code in order to give you results and error messages. It is going to struggle. Moore's law and all that.

Comment: Yes it is SwiftUI, I figured since storyboards were being deprecated slowly and I was just getting into it to be ahead of the curve instead of relearning what I knew later. I can see how the strict type-checking could be advantageous in some scenarios but I also feel like it can be restrictive in others, just a personal opinion I guess. The one that always seems to throw a type-checking error as of right now is when I try to iterate through a JSON object (using a list), and then use a function to get a picture for each, then crop that image into a circle. This would be very simple in web apps.